# How to use custom server for paperclip in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I want to use other server rather than paperclip supported server.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage

Paperclip support **File Storage**, **S3 Storage (via aws-sdk)** and **Fog Storage** and for other server like windows server it provide other gem like "**paperclip-azure-storage**" and "**paperclip-dropbox**".

But **paperclip-azure-storage** use only for Windows Azure. And talk about **Dropbox** then it's gem warn that

> This gem is not maintained anymore and became obsolete. Over time
>   Dropbox made some significant changes to its API, which breaks this
>   gem's core functionality. You shouldn't be using it anymore.

Now talking about custom server then which step i have to follow.

Ex. my custom server is ABC(Not S3, Fog, Windows Azure, Dropbox) then how i can configure with paperclip to store image on ABC server (**GoDaddy server**).

Any common way to store image on other server then please tell me i really need this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using fog storage as it supports 46 different providers.

You can check if you custom 'ABC' server is supported by fog [here](http://fog.io/about/provider_documentation.html).

Comment: i used godaddy server for storage and it's not listed in fog storage provider list. So how can i configure paperclip with godaddy server storage ?